# Permanently excluding folders from being checked in

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

Every time I want to check my code into my VSTS repository, I need to tell Visual Studio 2017 to exclude a few folders such as `node_modules`, `wwwroot/dist`, etc.

How do I mark these folders as excluded so that VS doesn't have to ask me every time I need to check my code in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a .tfignore file as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/add-files-server#customize-which-files-are-ignored-by-version-control) to achieve it in team foundation version control (tfvc). If you are using Git version control with VSTS it is [gitignore](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).